# Is there a canonical way to cache expanded makefile variables across runs?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

At the beginning of my makefile, I'm creating a dependency list for every perl script that gets executed, like so:

```
deps_script_1 := $(shell perl $(src)/local_deps.pl $(src)/script_1.pl $(src))
deps_script_2 := $(shell perl $(src)/local_deps.pl $(src)/script_2.pl $(src))
...
deps_script_N := $(shell perl $(src)/local_deps.pl $(src)/script_N.pl $(src))
```

These variables are used later like so:

```
output_1: $(src)/script_1.pl $(input_1) $(deps_script_1)
        $< $(input_1) > $@
```

I've already reduced each invocation of local_deps.pl from 5 seconds to <1 second, but as my list of scripts grows, it's still tedious.

I *could* teach local_deps.pl to cache dependency lists and when to invalidate, but that involves more shell. FYI, invalidation occurrs when the modified time on $(src)/lib/perl is newer than the respective output file.

Is there a way to cache and invalidate natively in my makefile?

Comment: When `$(src)/lib/perl/` is newer than `output_N`, should `output_N` be rebuilt? (I'm supposing that when Make runs `local_deps.pl` and generates the new list of preqs for `output_N`, it finds that none of them is newer than `output_N`.)

Comment: output_N should only be rebuilt if the modules it depends on are newer than output_N. The modify time of $(src)/lib/perl is just a shortcut to tell if there *is* a module in $(src/lib/perl which is newer than output_N. Using $(src)/lib/perl's modification time directly would cause nearly everything to be rebuilt for any code change inside $(src)/lib/perl.

Comment: Also, local_deps.pl doesn't detect if dependencies are newer. It passes all dependencies back, and forces make to decide.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the same approach as for dependency auto-generation with GCC.

```
output_1: $(src)/script_1.pl $(input_1)
    $< $(input_1) > $@
    @perl $(src)/local_deps.pl $< $(<D) > $@.d

-include output_1.d
```

See also: [Advanced Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/autodep.html) article.

### UPD.

The `output_1.d` file should contain something like:

```
output_1 : dep_1 ... dep_N

dep_1 ... dep_N :
```

The first line instructs Make to rebuild the `output_1` if some of `dep_X` files are newer then the target. The second line avoids Make to fail with an error in case when you delete one of the prerequisites.

Comment: Great article. From what I understand about your solution, I don't see how changing a dependency will cause output_1 to be rebuilt. Is your idea the following? 1. make a script_1.d: script_1.pl rule to make script_1.d contain the following if script_1.pl changes: deps_script_1 := <dependencies found by local_deps.pl>. 2. -include script_1.d. 3. list script_1.d AND $(deps_script_1) as a prerequisite for output_1.

Comment: asked another way, given your solution, what do I need to add to output_1's prerequisites, and what does output_1.d need to contain, in order to have make rebuild output_1 if something script_1.pl *depends on* has been changed (but not script_1.pl itself)?

Comment: @Chris, oh, sorry, I forgot about the syntax. The file should contain a line with make-style dependency, like `output_1 : dep_1 ... dep_N`. So the only change to `local_deps.pl` script you have to make is to prepend the name of the target file with a colon.